# JUnit5 CsvFileSource - escape comma (after double quotes)

Tags: csv, junit5, parametrized-testing

I haven't found a way to escape the **`,`** character in CSV resource file that is used by `CsvFileSource` `junit5` annotation. Consequently, any string containing comma is cut in half and the second part is never used.

Is there some workaround for this?

---

**EDIT**: The original question was not complete. The problem is I have commas and double quotes in my resource. Parametrized tests deal with the quotes but not with both.

*Example CSV line:*

```csv
5,10,5,53,"</identity/partners?limit=5&cursor=5>; rel="prev", </identity/partners?limit=5&cursor=15>; rel="next""
```

Quotes are escaped correctly but only until a wild comma appears (that is the algorithm I might guess).

So the resulting assert looks like this:

```csv
"Link" was not "\"</identity/partners?limit=5&cursor=5>; rel=\"prev\"", was "</identity/partners?limit=5&cursor=5>; rel="prev", </identity/partners?limit=5&cursor=15>; rel="next""
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your value in **double quotes**: `"first, value", second, third and last one`

More details here: http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-CsvFileSource

In your case, you may specify an entire different **delimiter** character in the annotation: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.params/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/CsvFileSource.html#delimiter()

But then it is no longer "comma" separated values...

Comment: Naturally I've tried that (I might be stupid but not that stupid) but it does not work for me. The problem is I have double quotes in my values as well. Sorry the question was incomplete, I did not see it in the first place.

Comment: OK now when I see it my problem is kind of an edge case - I need to escape a comma after double quotes. I understand if this is never implemented...

Comment: You may specify an entire different delimiter character in the annotation: http://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/CsvFileSource.html#delimiter--
But then it is no longer "comma" separated values...

Comment: Ha I didn't know about that, that is exactly the workaround I needed. Thank you and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Fine, then I'll rewrite the comment as an answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

If someone lands in this page looking for an answer, here is an example I used in my tests to meet the goal to be able to use these string values in my test (Note: it doesn’t escapes comma but achieves goal to run tests that includes comma in input. You can use any delimiter you wish).

```
@ParameterizedTest(name = "Product details for product number - {0}")
@CsvSource(value = {"0; Sauce Labs Backpack;carry.allTheThings() with the sleek, streamlined Sly Pack that melds uncompromising style with unequaled laptop and tablet protection."
        ,"1; Sauce Labs Bike Light;A red light isn't the desired state in testing but it sure helps when riding your bike at night. Water-resistant with 3 lighting modes, 1 AAA battery included."
}, delimiter = ';')
void assertThatProductDescriptionIsCorrectForAStandardUser(Integer productNumber, String productSummary, String productDescription) {
    String url = String.format("%s/%s", swagItemDetails, productNumber);
    deepLink.deepLinkToScreen(url , packageName);

    assertAll("Product Details"
            , () -> assertEquals(productSummary, productScreen.getProductSummary())
            , () -> assertEquals(productDescription, productScreen.getProductDescriptionByText(productDescription))
    );
}
```

Comment: Found this question on google after looking for a way to do it with `@CsvSource` and this was more useful (even if the original question was for `@CsvFileSource`, which I think gets used less often than `@CsvSource` anyways)